# Asp File upload control if has file

Tags: jquery, asp.net, webforms

I have a file upload like this:

```html
<asp:FileUpload id="FileUploadControl" runat="server" />
    <asp:Button runat="server" id="UploadButton" class="btn btn-default disabled" text="Upload" onclick="UploadButton_Click" />
    <br /><br />
    <asp:Label runat="server" id="StatusLabel" text="Upload status: " />
```

and the code behind:

```c#
protected void UploadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(FileUploadControl.HasFile)
    {
        try
        {
            string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUploadControl.FileName);
            FileUploadControl.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/") + filename);
            StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: File uploaded!";
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: The file could not be uploaded. The following error occured: " + ex.Message;
        }
    }
}
```

I want something to check if fileupload has file and active my button UploadButton...exactly change the CSS Class to btn btn-default active. I don't now if is possible??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add FileUpload onchange event client side, and then with javascript update its classes, like this:

```
<asp:FileUpload id="FileUploadControl" onchange="activateButton()" runat="server" />
<asp:Button runat="server" id="UploadButton" class="btn btn-default disabled" text="Upload" onclick="UploadButton_Click" />
```

and in javascript:

```
<script>
    function activateButton() {
        document.getElementById("<%=UploadButton.ClientID%>").className = "btn btn-default active";
    }
</script>
```

This is plain javascript, if you are already using jquery, can achieve the same with it (look at @avi answer for details).

Answer (score 3):

I think this should be better done using jquery. Try something like:

```
$("#fileinput").change(function() {  
    $("#yourbutton").removeClass("disabled").addClass("active");
});
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/s4orghjd/) is a sample. You should do the proper replaces for id.

Comment: You can just do: `$("#yourbutton").removeClass('disabled').addClass("active");`

Answer (score 1):

You should use `RequiredFieldValidator` to check whether a file is selected or not, if not, then do not let the page post back even if button is clicked.

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvFileupload" runat="server"
                                                ControlToValidate="FileUpload1"/>
```

You wont be able to post back until a file is chosen using File Upload control.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(".FileUploadControl").on('change', function() {
         if (document.getElementById('<%= FileUploadControl.ClientID %>').files.length === 0) 
  {
  // File upload do not have file
 }
 else {
    // File upload has file
    $(".FileUploadControl").addClass("btn btn-default active");
 }
});
```